# How can I pull one item, from a list of dictionary items, using a single key:value pair?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, variables

Let's say I have a list of dictionary items:

```
main_dict = [{'Player': '1', 'position': 'main', 'points': 50},
{'Player': '2', 'position': 'main', 'points': 60},
{'Player': '3', 'position': 'main', 'points': 70},
{'Player': '4', 'position': 'main', 'points': 80},
{'Player': '5', 'position': 'main', 'points': 90}]
```

I ran some code and got this result:
`90`

I now want to pull the full dictionary item, from index in the list, using only the value of the points key.

```
if points == 90:
    new_item = (#find item in main_dict[4])
```

```
output: {'Player': '5', 'position': 'main', 'points': 90}
```

How can I pull the full item out of list, using only the unique value of 90?

Comment: `[d for d in main_dict if d['points'] == 90]`. If `90` is unique this will be a list of one dictionary. Alternatively if you know 90 is unique, you can just grab it with `next(d for d in main_dict if d['points'] == 90)` This will raise an exception if the value doesn't exist, however.

Comment: Why don't you pull the full item out in the first place, instead of just the 90?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` built-in should do the trick. If you want to match all items:

```
new_item = list(filter(lambda x: x['points'] == 90, main_dict))
```

if you want only the first item which matches:

```
new_item = next(filter(lambda x: x['points'] == 90, main_dict))
```

Comment: You are AMAZING, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
main_dict = [{'Player': '1', 'position': 'main', 'points': 50},
{'Player': '2', 'position': 'main', 'points': 60},
{'Player': '3', 'position': 'main', 'points': 70},
{'Player': '4', 'position': 'main', 'points': 80},
{'Player': '5', 'position': 'main', 'points': 90}]

def getDict(i):
    for retDict in main_dict:
        if i == retDict.get('points'):
            return(retDict)

print(getDict(90))
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I already picked one that fits my full program better, but this was also great! Gave you an upvote!

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter the list to dicts with `'points': 90` using list comprehension:

```
[inner_dict for inner_dict in main_dict if inner_dict['points'] == 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I'm gonna assume this is an XY problem and you should just get the item directly, without first finding the points value. For example if you want the player with the most points:

```
>>> max(main_dict, key=lambda d: d['points'])
{'Player': '5', 'position': 'main', 'points': 90}
```